# Why am I getting an error 'Class "XSLTProcessor" not found' using PHP / Xampp / Laravel / Windows

Tags: php, laravel, xslt, xampp

I'm trying to implement some code that uses the XSLTProcessor class in PHP.

I have a local project that is running on Xampp on Windows and using Laravel.

The line:

```
    $proc = new XSLTProcessor;
```

Is reporting the error:

```
local.ERROR: Class "XSLTProcessor" not found
```

After some Googling I've so far tried the following:

I've removed the semi-colon from this line
`extension=xsl`
In php.ini in the Xampp directory

I've restarted my Apache server from the Control Panel.

I've run a `php -i` command and it reports back:

```
xsl

XSL => enabled
libxslt Version => 1.1.37
libxslt compiled against libxml Version => 2.10.2
EXSLT => enabled
libexslt Version => 0.8.20
```

I've included the following line at the top of my php file:

```
use XSLTProcessor;
```

The pertinent part of my code is:

```
    // LOAD XML
    $xml = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
    $xml->load($xmlFile);
    
    // LOAD XSLT 
    $xsl = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');   
    $xsl->load($pathToMyXSLFile);

    // INITIALIZE TRANSFORMER
    $proc = new XSLTProcessor;
    $proc->importStyleSheet($xsl);
    
    // PASS PARAMETER VALUES
    $proc->setParameter('', 'find-value', $findParam);
    $proc->setParameter('', 'replace-value', $replaceParam);

    // TRANSFORM SOURCE
    $new_xml = $proc->transformToDoc($xml);
```

And the line that I'm getting the error on is:

```
$proc = new XSLTProcessor;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just managed to fix this but thought I'd answer my own question rather than deleting it - just in case it helps someone else in the future.

As well as restarting the Apache server on the control panel I had to shut down my command prompt windows - then right-click in my Project folder - start another command prompt and restart `php artisan serve` in order to restart the server.

This appears to be working now.

Answer (score 0):

Running `php -i` on the console will execute the PHP CLI Binary. The webserver most likely uses on of the SAPI libraries.

Use a PHP page with `phpinfo()` to check the PHP configuration used by the PHP in the webserver.

Make sure that the configuration file is the right one and has the extension enabled.

If you just changed the configuration you will need to restart the webserver and/or the PHP SAPI (php-fpm). They cache configuration and reuse PHP processes for performance.

The PHP CLI calls are a new process, always.